# How to intercept out-going http calls and set the the JWT token in Nestjs micro-service

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

I'am developing a Nestjs micro-service and need to parse the incoming JWT in the request to the outgoing http requests, but seems like there is no cleaner way to do that, or am I missing something?
This is what I have done so far

**Note: Using nestjs axios http client**

**user.contoller.ts**

```
@Controller('/users')
export class UserController {
   constructor(private userService: userService,
      private vehicleService: VehicleService){}

   @Post()
   create(@Req() req: Request, @Body() userData: userData) {
    // I can get the JWT token from here
    // fetch some data from different micro-service
     const d = this.vehicleService.getVehicleById(userData.vehicleId, req.headers['authorization'])
    // save user
   }
}
```

**vehicle.service.ts**

@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {
basePath = `http://ms-vehicles/api/v1/vehicles`;

```
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  getVehicleById(vehicleId: string, token: string) {
    return this.httpSerice.get(this.basePath + '/' + vehicleId,
     {headers: {Authorization: token});
  }
}
```

We can intercept the outgoing http calls using axios interceptor, but How can I set the correct token from there, without parsing the token through the the controller and service as a parameter

Found [below solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105763/nestjs-passing-authorization-header-to-httpservice) in the stack overflow and I'am not sure this is the right way to do this.

**interceptor**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpServiceInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
  
    // ** if you use normal HTTP module **
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const token = ctx.getRequest().headers['authorization'];

    // ** if you use GraphQL module **
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const token = ctx.getContext().token;

    if (ctx.token) {
      this.httpService.axiosRef.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] =
        token;
    }
    return next.handle().pipe();
  }
}
```

Register interceptor in main module as global one

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: HttpServiceInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

if I use above solution, can we guarantee that someone else's token will not be used in other requests, because this common headers available for any places where we used httpService? or am I worong?

Comment: I think the `req.headers['authorization']` value in controller is `"Bearer xxxYOUR_TOKENxxx"`, however, in your service, you prepend `Bearer` again to the value, so your authorization header become `"Bearer Bearer xxxYOUR_TOKENxxx"`

Comment: sorry I have updated the question, it was a mistake in the question, not in the code

Comment: I don't think you can use `httpService.axiosRef.defaults`. That is a reference to the module imported `Axios` which is shared everywhere that copy of axios is imported.

Comment: Do you mean "pass" as in "send to", rather than "parse"? I think it's "pass", the way the question is written, but parse could actually work too, so don't want to edit it =)

Comment: yes, httpService.axiosRef.defaults is shared everywhare and not gonna help in my case. Thanks @Matt