# How to pass headers from incoming request to outgoing request?

Tags: nestjs

I have a simple service which works as proxy. It gets incoming requests and passes it to another API. I have to pass authorization header in every method and I would like to avoid code duplication. Which tool for it does NestJS have?

```
// Controller
@Get('GetAllItems') 
  async getAllItems(
    @Headers() headers: AxiosRequestHeaders,
  ): Promise<AllItemsDto> {
    try {     
      return await this.itemService.getAllItems({
        authorization: headers.authorization, // <- narrow place
      });
    } catch (e) {     
      throw new HttpException('Error');
    }
  }

// Service
public async getAllItems(
    headers: AxiosRequestHeaders,
  ): Promise<AllItemsDto> {
    const response = await this.http.axiosRef.get(
      `${process.env.BE_URL}/GetAllItems`,
      { headers }, // <- narrow place
    );
    return response.data;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interceptors to manipulate the requests automatically.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
  
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const token = ctx.getRequest().headers['authorization'];

    if (token) {
      this.httpService.axiosRef.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] =
        token;
    }
    return next.handle().pipe();
  }
}
```

Apply the interceptor to your controller class using the `@UseInterceptor()` annotation.

```
@UseInterceptors(AuthInterceptor)
export class Controller {}
```

Kudos to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69524183/4529555

Comment: Just small fix: 'if (token)' instead of 'if (ctx.token)'